# Method to find all indices in List<Long> corresponding to some element

Tags: java, list, arraylist, indexing, indices

Suppose I have an `long` called `X` and a `List<Long>` called `foo` which contains `X` as one non-unique element among many elements. What is the method I need to apply to find all the indices in `foo` that correspond to the `X`. This `foo` is not necessarily sorted (but a good answer may assume this if there is a specific method that requires sorting - I am interested in both sorted and unsorted cases).

For example this could be the problem setup:

```
long X = 5L
List<Long> foo = new ArrayList<Long>();
foo.add(4L);
foo.add(5L);
foo.add(5L);
foo.add(6L);
foo.add(7L);
```

I want the method to accept `X` as an argument and return a list (or other object) that contains the indices `1` and `2`, since they correspond to the locations of `X` within `foo`.

Trivially,

```
public static List<Long> locator(long target, List<Long> fooList) {
   List<Long> output = new ArrayList<Long>();

   for(int i = 0 ; i < foo.size() ; i++) {
      if(foo.get(i) == target) {
         output.add(i);
      }
   }

   return output;
}
```

But I want a faster way incase my `foo` is gigantically long.

Comment: What do you mean by more efficient way? Is your list always sorted?

Comment: @RohitJain Something that runs faster than my method for large lists. My list may or may not be sorted. I want answers for both unsorted and sorted cases.

Comment: I don't think you can get any better than `O(n)`.

Comment: A `List<Long>` is really, really inefficient to start with. If you care about efficiency, I am not sure why you are using it or why you are building an index of matches.

Comment: @PeterLawrey What would be better to hold non-unique `long` values?

Comment: `if(foo.get(i) - X == (long) 0)` is the same as `if(foo.get(i) == X)`

Comment: @user2763361 An `long[]` or a wrapper like `TLongArrayList` would use less than 1/3 of the memory for a start and it wouldn't have to follow so many references to get the values. Next I would look at the values to see if a more compact structure would be better.  Lastly, I wouldn't build an index, instead I would do whatever you intend to do with the index as you find matches.

Answer (score 1):

If the list is sorted, stop after you hit something larger.  If the list implementation allows random access (i.e. an `ArrayList`) then use a binary search.  Since the list contains duplicates you will need to scan forward and backwards from the found element to make sure you get all the indexes.

If the ratio of searches to updates is large (lots more searches than updates) then you can maintain an index in a `Map<Long,List<Integer>>` that maps each value to a list of indexes where the value appears in the list.  You will have to write code to maintain the index as the original list gets updated.

In evaluating performance, the cost of building and maintaining the index can be amortized over the searches. If the list is never updated after being created, and the number of searches is large, then this will be a clear winner.

However, unless the list is large (> 10000) AND the number of queries is large (> 1,000,000) it may not be worth the trouble.

Comment: If it is sorted you can use binary search to find the start and the end in O(ln N) time.

Comment: True, but only if it's a random access list

Comment: A LinkedList of Long is even more inefficient than I could imagine. +1 btw for the prebuilt index.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [GS Collections](http://github.com/goldmansachs/gs-collections) you can use primitive lists for both the source list and the indices list, so you won't incur the cost of boxing the primitive values.  The following code would work in Java 8 using lambdas with your example:

```
long X = 5L;
LongArrayList list = LongArrayList.newListWith(4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L);
IntArrayList indices = new IntArrayList();
list.forEachWithIndex((each, index) -> { if (each == X) indices.add(index);});
Assert.assertEquals(IntArrayList.newListWith(1, 2), indices);
```

In Java 7 it would look as follows:

```
long X = 5L;
LongArrayList list = LongArrayList.newListWith(4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L);
IntArrayList indices = new IntArrayList();
list.forEachWithIndex(new LongIntProcedure() 
{
    public void value(long each, int index) 
    {
        if (each == X) indices.add(index);
    }
});
Assert.assertEquals(IntArrayList.newListWith(1, 2), indices);
```

**Note:** I am a developer on GS Collections.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
int firstIndex = foo.indexOf(X);

int count = Collections.frequency(foo, X);
```

If your `List` is **sorted**, therefore you have 2 positions: `firstIndex` and `firstIndex + 1`

From your example:

```
long X = 5L
List<Long> foo = new ArrayList<Long>();
foo.add(4L);
foo.add(5L);
foo.add(5L);
foo.add(6L);
foo.add(7L);

int firstIndex = foo.indexOf(X); // 1
int count = Collections.frequency(foo, X); // 2

List<Long> output = new ArrayList<Long>();

for(int i=firstIndex; i<count; i++ ){
  output.add(i);
}
```

Comment: If you know there is exactly two values, you don't need to look them up.  Don't you mean `lastIndex - firstIndex + 1`